# Suspend/Hibernate/restore and Reboot problems 15.04 Dell Inspiron 3451

Tags: dell, suspend, power-management, hibernate, restore

There are many posts and questions about problems with lid closing leading to operating system states which require hard reboots; these reports come from  across multiple kernels and releases of Ubuntu.  I am working with a 3.19.0.26 kernel, 15.04 Ubuntu (32 bit), and a Dell Inspriron 3451.  Some have suggested adding programs to the sleep.d folder (although this has not led to success for me, yet), others have suggested setting acpi=off in the boot loader options (also, not successful for me). Others have suggested moving to the upstream kernels (have not tried yet), and I am aware that these particular models are not certified by Canonical for Hibernate or Hybrid Suspend, but I do not yet understand if this rules out all options. Even a "stay running" option would be preferable.

All I am hoping to do is to have a valid OS when I re-open the lid.   It is not clear to me which path I might pursue - boot options, programs in sleep.d, etc. I'd welcome tactical advise and I am running from place to place without a plan.

Suggestions sought.

R

Answer (score 0):

Is this laptop running on the newer Intel Atom SoC CPUs by any chance (Celeron / Pentium Nxxx)?

Did you experience problems while installing the system or did you take any advanced options (turning of ACPI before the installation, etc.)?

As far as I know, this problem is common with the above mentioned processors and the only solution I've found so far was to blacklist the module "dw_dmac", by doing the following:

Open a terminal window, then enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

In the opened file, add the following lines:

```
blacklist dw_dmac
blacklist dw_dmac_core
```

Then save with Ctrl+O and close the file with Ctrl+X.

Now, hibernation should work.

If this does not work for you, I don't see an option for you besides reinstalling the system. You could either try the new kernel on 15.10 when it is released tomorrow or go back to 12.04, which should work reliably for you, if you are not in need of using a newer version, at least for a while.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and report. It is a Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz × 2  processor.

Comment: That did not work, even after a reboot. I have set up the system to "do nothing" on lid closure, but  the mouse freezes, and the system no longer takes keyboard input, so... Did it freeze when I closed the lid? Did it fail to unfreeze when I reopened the lid? Do I need to repartition the drive so that there is space to "put" an image dump?   Ahh, many questions.

Comment: What did not work, the blacklist? You might want to try different ACPI options in the GRUB settings and see if this fixes it (there are more settings than ACPI=off). Did you try Ubuntu 12.04 yet or is this not an option?